# Definition of Topological Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, field-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Wikipedia's definition of a topological field is as follows

> Let $(\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{F})$ be a topological space and $(\mathsf{F}, +, \times)$ be a field. We say that $(\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{F}, +, \times)$ is a topological field if addition, multiplication, $i_+:a\mapsto -a$ and $i_\times:a\mapsto a^{-1}$ are continuous maps.

#### Issue: Continuity of $a\mapsto a^{-1}$

I have an issue understanding continuity of the map $i_\times$. This map is defined on all of $\mathsf{F}$ except the additive identity $0_\mathsf{F}$
$$
i_\times:\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}\to\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}.
$$
Continuity would then mean that for any $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}}$ one has $i_\times^{-1}(\mathsf{A})\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}}$.  How do I know that I can find a topology for $\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}$? How do I know $(\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}, \mathcal{T}_{\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}})$ is a topological space?

Comment: Use the usual subspace topology on $\mathsf{F}\backslash\{0_\mathsf{F}\}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology

Comment: Before diving into topological algebra, you should be familiar with (at least) the three basic methods of constructing new spaces from old ones: **product spaces**, **subspaces**, and **quotient spaces**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you! Do you have any good topology reference by any chance? My main goal is to learn topology for statistics